# Spring oauth/token returns 404 Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth

I am getting a 404 Error using Spring oAuth2 Authentication. My web.xml looks like this :

```
   <!-- Servlets -->
   <servlet>    
       <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
       </servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

When I change the url-pattern to '/*', I will get Status 200 with access token. This is the remaining code segment in web.xml :

```
      <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,                     
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->

 <!-- filters -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
      <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.servlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

I want to make this work using `<url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>`. Please help.